# I can't get over a resolution of 640x480 after upgrading to 12.04, how can I fix it?

Tags: resolution, monitor

Ever since I upgraded to 12.04 my screen resolution has gone down to 640 x 480, even though I had higher resolutions before.

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480         0.0* 

$ lspci -nnk | grep -A5 VGA 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device [8086:2562] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5641]
    Kernel modules: i915
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:24c2] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5641]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
```

How can I get higher resolutions? I know that my monitor supports higher resolutions.

Comment: It's highly likely that you are not using the correct drivers, edit your question and include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A5 VGA`.

Comment: I downloaded the latest intel drivers by following the instructions at the below link  http://www.techlw.com/2012/08/install-latest-intel-gpu-drivers-in.html and every thing start working again. Thanks alot.

Comment: Can you write that as an answer below so everyone could be benefited of the solution?